# Warum die Buchstabenkombinationen „sch“ und „ch“

Tags: history, spelling

Woher kommen die Buchstabenkombinationen *sch* und *ch*?

Die Herkunft der Buchstabenkombination *ch* für den stimmlosen velaren Frikativ oder den stimmlosen palatalen Frikativ ist noch vergleichsweise leicht nachvollziehbar. In holprigen linguistischen Termini ausgedrückt stellt das *ch* ursprünglich einen angehauchten *k*-Laut dar. Dies findet sich noch wieder in der süddeutschen Aussprache des anlautenden *ch*, wie in *Chemie* als *Kemie*, oder im Berliner Dialekt, wie *Ich* als *ik*.

Für die Herkunft der Schreibweise *sch* bietet nur das Englische einen Hinweis. Das englische *school* wurzelt vermutlich in der simplen Kombination eines *s*-Lautes mit einem wie auch immer ausgesprochenen *ch*.

Ich weiß nicht, inwieweit diese Mutmaßungen korrekt sind. Kann jemand dazu verlässliche Informationen liefern?

Comment: Swedisch *skola*, gesprochen ungefähr /skula/ (bitte die Vokale nicht auf die Goldwaage legen!) bietet den gleichen Hinweis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Betrachten wir mal das Wort *Schule*. Das wurde aus dem lateinischen *schola* abgeleitet, was wiederum vom griechischen *σχολή* abstammt.

Das [englische Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%AE#Ancient_Greek) nennt Aussprachen aus unterschiedlichen Epochen:

> (5th BC Attic): IPA: /skʰolɛ͜ɛ́/
>   (1st BC Egyptian): IPA: /skʰoléː/
>   (4th AD Koine): IPA: /sxolí/
>   (10th AD Byzantine): IPA: /skolí/
>   (15th AD Constantinopolitan): IPA: /skolí/

Wie man sieht, blieb die Aussprache immer ungefähr bei *sk*. Mit *sk* wurde es vermutlich auch in Latein ausgesprochen.

Verändert hat es sich [laut Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch_(Trigraph)) erst später:

> Historisch handelt es sich ursprünglich nicht um eine Schreibung für den postalveolaren Zischlaut, sondern um einen Aussprachewandel: Ältere Aussprache war im Deutschen, Italienischen und den nordgermanischen Sprachen aspiriertes oder nichtaspiriertes [sk] oder [ʃk], das in den genannten Sprachen, teils nur vor bestimmten anderen Lauten, unter Verlust des [k] zu [ʃ] wurde.

Natürlich hat es sich nicht überall gleich verändert. Im Italienischen heißt es nun *scuola*, auf Spanisch *escuela*, auf Englisch *school*, alle gesprochen mit *sk*. Auf Französisch sagt man hingegen *école*, also nur mit *k*.

Bei anderen Wörtern ist die Ausspracheveränderung ähnlich abgelaufen.

Derselbe Laut kommt auch in anderen Buchstabenkombinationen im Deutschen vor: *sp, st*

Auch *sn* konnte man eine Zeit lang als *schn* aussprechen. Am Ende wurde es aber zu *schn* angepasst. Beispiele dafür sind *Schnecke* und *schnacken* (reden, plaudern). Letzteres wird auf Plattdeutsch immer noch *snacken* gesprochen.

Das *ch* hat den Ursprung, den du vermutest.

Beispielsweise kommt *Chemie* über Umwege aus dem Griechischen *χημεία*. Auch *Charisma* kommt daher: *χάρισμα*. Wikipedia sagt zum ersten Buchstaben [Chi](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi):

> In der Antike betrug der Lautwert dieses Buchstabens einen aspirierten stimmlosen velaren Plosiv (/kʱǐː̂/). Die Aussprache im modernen Griechisch ist ähnlich wie das „ch“ in „ich“, seltener wie das „ch“ in „ach“ (jeweils als Beispiel in der deutschen Sprache).

Also wurde *ch* der ursprünglich *kh* ausgesprochen. Auch bei Wörtern mit anderem Ursprung ist das sicher. Auf Englisch heißt es *make* und *milk*, auf Deutsch *machen* und *Milch*.

Comment: Nur als Notiz: Ich frage mich, ob das russische Snak, знак, mit dt. schnacken oder ndl. snacken verwandt ist.

Comment: Laut Duden ist die Herkunft vom deutschen `schnacken`: `(mittel)niederdeutsch snacken, lautmalend`
Die von `знак` aber laut en. Wiktionary: `From Proto-Slavic *znakъ.`

Comment: Im Französischen ist einfach nur das s ausgefallen, vgl. franz. `état` von lat. `status`.

Answer (score 1):

Die Logik der deutschen Schreibung sch wie in Schule für das lateinische scola, gesprochen /skola/ ist einfach. Das h deutet an, dass sich die lateinische Lautkombination /sk/ im Deutschen verändert hat.

Analog wurde der ich-Laut und ach-Laut, der im lateinischen Alphabet nicht vorhanden war, mit c+h geschrieben um anzuzeigen, dass sich der lateinische k-Laut im Deutschen verändert hat. Vergleiche lat. nox/noct-is und deutsch Nacht.