# Warum wurden "sch" und "ch" nicht diakritikalisiert?

Tags: history, spelling, diacritic

Wir sehen für *ä*, *ü* und *ö* eine Entwicklung zu einem diakritischen Zeichen:

> ue => uͤ => ü

Ähnliches gibt es auch in anderen Sprachen:

> fenestra => fenêtre

Im Deutschunterricht wurde uns das so erklärt, dass man teures Pergament sparen wollte und deshalb zunächst den einen Buchstaben drübergeschrieben und dann abgeschliffen hat.
Warum hat man aber nicht angefangen, *sch* oder *ch* als etwa *Š* oder *ĉ* zu schreiben? Ich finde es generell etwas seltsam, dass es im Deutschen nur vier Sonderzeichen gibt und der Rest über Umschreibungen oder schlichtes Lernen, was wann was ist, geregelt wurde. Das umso mehr, als dass andere Sprachen um Deutschland nicht mit Diakritika geizen.

Generell bin ich erstaunt darüber, wie wenig die lateinische Schrift für das Deutsche verändert wurde.

Comment: Im germanischen Zweig findet man (vom Isländischen/Färöischen einmal abgesehen) generell nicht viele Diakritika. Die skandinavischen Sprachen, das Niederländische und natürlich das Englische besitzen ebenfalls kaum Sonderzeichen. Eigentlich halte ich das auch nicht für nötig - übersichtlicher oder logischer sind Sprachen voller Akzente und Diakritika selten.

Comment: Wäre wôl ein Anlass für eine brandneue Reɕtŝreibreform! Denken wir aber daran, wí víle Tastaturen, Automaten und Druckmaŝinen für dísen Zweck ersetzt werden müssten! Dí Kosten gingen in dí Milliarden!

Comment: Man könnte auch sagen, das Lateinische hatte keine Zusatszeichen und man wollte so nahe wie möglich am lateinischen Alphabet bleiben. Also ist man mit Zusatzzeichen sparsam umgegangen (ä ö ü). Aber man hat ß eingeführt, das eigentlich nur stört, und das man nur schwer wieder los wird.

Comment: @ rogermue — "ß" ist eine paläografische bzw. typografische Ligatur aus "s" und "z" resp. Binnen-S und End-S.

Comment: Hab in der WP einen interessanten Absatz gefunden, der besagte, dass die Ansicht, dass das Fraktur-ß aus einer Ligatur aus Binnen-s und End-s entstanden sei, nicht haltbar sei und auf einer weit verbreiteten aber unfundierten Quelle (Jan Tschichold) basiert.  Ich bin ja nicht wirklich vom Fach, aber das überraschte mich doch, und wollte es Euch nicht vorenthalten.

Comment: @Veredomon: In "Historische Sprachwissenschaft des Deutschen: Eine Einführung in ..." von Nübling steht (S.180): "...Im Mhd. kommt [ʃ] hinzu, das sich u.a. über [sχ] aus [sk] entwickelt hat ... Auch hier kam es zu vielen Schreibvarianten. Dem sich durchsetzenden Trigraph <sch> lag die Analyse als Laut zwischen [s] <s> und [χ] <ch> zugrunde (MUNSKE 2005a:52f.)...". Du musst dir also mal "Lob der Rechtschreibung. Warum wir schreiben, wie wir schreiben" von Munske besorgen, denn da steht es wohl erklärt, warum es so kam wie es kam. Es gibt leider keine Online-Version davon.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/warum-die-buchstabenkombinationen-sch-und-ch

Comment: @Œlrim Wobei sich die nichtlateinischen Sonderzeichen bei Färöisch/Isländisch mW aus Runen ableiten lassen, also auch wieder nur »Tradition« sind ;)

Answer (score 2):

## ch

Das *ch* wurde als Schreibweise für das griechische χ (chi) benutzt. Jenes wurde aspiriert ausgesprochen ([kʰ]), genauso wie φ (phi) und θ (theta), weswegen man ein *h* an den Grundbuchstaben *c* angefügt hat. Dann gab es Lautverschiebung hin zu [x]. Dieser Prozess hätte sicherlich auch diakritisch erfolgen können, aber das war damals vermutlich nicht in Mode. Später blieb die Schreibweise einfach.

## sch

Das *sch* entstand aus [sk] über [sx]. Letzteres wurde, wie oben schon gesagt, durch *ch* geschrieben. Folglich hat man einfach die Konsonanten entsprechend ihrer Sprechweise hintereinander geschrieben. Erst später erfolgte die Lautverschiebung von [sx] zum heutigen [ʃ]. Eine diakritische Schreibweise macht hier wenig Sinn.