# Warum hat Deutsch manchmal ganze vier Buchstaben für nur einen Laut?

Tags: spelling

Beispiel: Deutsch, Tschechisch , ausgesprochen *dojč, čechiš*. Bin Tscheche (Čech), und da ist es in dieser Hinsicht einfacher.

Comment: ʧɛçɪʃ - t-sch. Warum nutzt das Tschechische einen Buchstaben für zwei Laute? Warum werden verschiedene laute identisch kodiert (I in Vieh, sie, gibt / ch in mich, mach)? Entsprechend umformuliert würde diese Frage deutlich interessanter und etwas neutraler

Comment: Relevant, vielleicht ein Duplikat: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/warum-die-buchstabenkombinationen-sch-und-ch

Comment: Ob man tsch nun als einen oder zwei Laute zählen sollte…

Comment: Hi Edvin! "Warum" ist bei Sprachen immer eine schwierige Frage. Mir ist nicht ganz klar, was du als Antwort erwartest. Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-is-the-problem-with-why-questions-and-how-to-deal-with-them

Comment: in Lettisch bist du čehs, also nur 'h' für den dritten Laut

Comment: Würde eine Übersicht über die Geschichte der Phonographie des Deutschen deine Frage beantworten?

Answer (score 1):

Die deutsche Buchstabenfolge *»tsch«* codiert nicht einen Laut, sondern zwei Laute, nämlich [t] und [ʃ]. Dasselbe gilt für das tschechische C mit Hatschek welches dieselbe Lautfolge codiert.

Ob ein diakritisches Zeichen *über* einem anderen Zeichen einfacher ist als ein (oder zwei) Zeichen *vor* oder *hinter* einem anderen, wage ich mal heftig zu bezweifeln. So muss ich z.B. sehr oft meinen Namen absichtlich falsch (nämlich mit *»oe«* statt *»ö«*) schreiben, damit er von diversen IT-Systemen (z.B. Sozialversicherung) akzeptiert wird. Tschechische Sonderzeichen sind da sicher nicht besser als deutsch Umlaute.

---

Dafür, dass man gewisse Laute mit mehr als nur einem Zeichen schreibt, gibt es einen einfachen Grund: Es gibt im Deutschen erheblich mehr Laute als Buchstaben. In vielen Fällen behilft man sich damit, dass ähnliche Laute mit demselben Buchstaben geschrieben werden (beispielsweise stehen die drei *»e«* in *»vergeben«* für drei ganz unterschiedliche Laute). Manche Laute schreib man hingegen eben mit mehreren Buchstaben (z.B. *»ng«* in *»Gong«*, *»ch«* in *»ich«*, *»ch«* in *»ach«*, usw.), und eben auch *»sch«* in *»schön«.*

---

Auf die Frage, warum etwas in einer lebenden Sprache so ist wie es ist, gibt es eigentlich immer dieselbe Antwort: Irgendwann in der Vergangenheit war das noch nicht so, dann hat irgendjemand damit angefangen. Anfangs nur eine Marotte, die sich innerhalb einer kleinen Gruppe etabliert hat, und im Lauf der Jahrhunderte hat sich diese Marotte über eine größere Population ausgebreitet, und einige dieser Marotten gelten seitdem im ganzen Sprachraum als Standard. Das erklärt wie das Hatschek in die tschechische Sprache gekommen sind und es erklärt wie das *sch* Bestandteil der deutschen Rechtschreibung wurde.

Mir ist klar, dass diese Erklärung nicht befriedigend ist, aber so funktioniert eben Evolution. Das gilt nicht nur für Lebewesen, sondern auch für lebende Sprachen. Beide folgen in ihrer Entwicklung denselben Regeln aus Zufall und Selektion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136211/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-warum-hat-deutsch-manchmal-ganze-vier-b).

Answer (score 0):

To be exact its 3 letters for one sound.
T and Sch are each a single sound.

The Sch appears in German frequently, and also its brother Ch.

Ch comes from "softening" a c with an h and therefore forming the [X] sound.

The Sch is adding an S to it. Try it. The only difference between Sch and Ch is that when you speak an Sch you raise your tongue as if you were forming an S

(Altough some linguists think Sch independently developed by softening the Old High German Sc [zk] to the Sch sound)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich stimme mit dem Inhalt aber nicht mit dem Ton deines Kommentars überein. Wir sollten freundlicher sein. Das Profil zeigt, dass Lilium noch nicht so lange hier dabei ist. Das siehst du auch, wenn du einen Kommentar verfasst: _Lilium is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct._ Vielleicht kennt Lilium die Regeln hier einfach noch nicht. Ich schätze dich und deine inhaltlichen Beiträge hier sehr. Es ist aber bedauerlich, dass ich dich zum wiederholten Male darauf aufmerksam machen muss, freundlicher zu sein, um den Code of Conduct zu respektieren.

Comment: Hi Lilium! 

In order to keep some order, we aim to have answers in the same language as the question. Your answer is in English, but the question is in German. Could you translate your answer to German? In case you want help with that, just let me know, I will be happy to assist.

For the reasoning why we want to keep languages of answers and questions aligned, have a look at: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question